# Not showing function (JavaScript, HTML, SQL)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want display the shop of this web https://oreplains.fr/server

[image]

Code:

- [html](https://hastebin.com/tedituyesa.xml)
- [shops.js](https://hastebin.com/vixuleyepe.js)
- [blocks_items.css](https://hastebin.com/arepabisih.css)

I don't see nothing:

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Hastebin's "[p]astes will stay for 30 days from their last view.  They may be removed earlier
and without notice."

Comment: And now that I've glanced at what you linked to, please cut that down to a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).